# if the user checks remember me on the asp login control, when will the user have to login again?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control, remember-me

just trying to get a better understanding of the concepts involved with this so i can make better decisions on implementing the login based on the requirements i've been given.

in the case where the user checks the remember me box,
how long does the asp login control's "remember me" remember for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is set to 50 years.

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.remembermeset%28vs.80%29.aspx):

> When the RememberMeSet property is true, the authentication cookie sent to the user's computer is set to expire in 50 years, making it a persistent cookie that will be used when the user next visits the Web site. Because the authentication cookie will be present on the user's computer, the user will be considered already authenticated and will not have to log in to the Web site again.

Comment: nice. so basically they'll have to login again after they cleared that cookie, either by logging out of the site or clearing broswer cookies etc. is there a way to override the default value?

Comment: @towps - This post (http://forums.asp.net/t/1124851.aspx/1) seems to have an answer down at the bottom.

Comment: there's a community post at the bottom of that MSDN page: Expiration date is not 50 years by default.
Add the following lines to your Web.config to correct it.

<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms timeout="26280000" />
</authentication>

Comment: @towps - Well, there's the same thing, just more concretely :)